What is the movement called when you put out a cigarette on the ground with your foot?
Like for example when you move your foot side to side. I don't know what that's called and I need help for writing a story.

Stamping, or less common, treading a cigarette out. In many UK towns and cities, you can get a fine of up to £150 (190 US dollars) for doing that in a public place.

"Grinding under your shoe" is another way of referring to it. To me, "stubbing" is (often repeatedly) pushing the lit end of a cigarette into an ashtray to extinguish it, which is not the same as crushing it lengthwise underfoot.
Collins Dictionary:

v. stubbing (usually followed by out) to extinguish (a cigarette or
cigar) by pressing the end against a surface


Merriam Webster dictionary gives the meaning as to extinguish (something, such as a cigarette) by crushing. Grinding doesn't indicate extinguishing a cigarette.

@JamesMathai It's the manner of crushing that is material here. If something falls on your toe, that's different from stubbing your toe on the table leg.

Extinguishing a cigarette with your foot expression.
OP can convey his meaning by adding under the foot for the words in website link below
For example

stubbed out/ stubbed/ snuffed out/  under his foot or with foot.

https://www.powerthesaurus.org/put_out_a_cigarette.
Stubbed out meaning from different dictionaries:

I. Ref. Merriam Webster dictionary
stub.
verb.
stubbed; stubbing.
transitive verb.
: to extinguish (something, such as a cigarette) by crushing
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stub#:~:text=%3A%20to%20extinguish%20(something%2C%20such,or%20toe)%20against%20an%20object.


II. Ref. Collins dictionary
stub out.
PHRASAL VERB.
When someone stubs out a cigarette, they put it out by pressing it against something hard.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stub-out#:~:text=Definition%20of%20'stub%20out'&text=When%20someone%20stubs%20out%20a,%5BAlso%20VERB%20noun%20PARTICLE%5D


III. Ref. Cambridge dictionary
stub something out.
phrasal verb with stub verb
to stop a cigarette from burning by pressing the burning end against a hard surface.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stub-out


IV. Ref. Oxford dictionary
stub out phrasal verb.
stub something out.
​to stop a cigarette, etc. from burning by pressing the end against something hard.
He stubbed out his cigarette in the ashtray.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stub-out


"stuff out", "stuffed" and [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/douse]("doused out") do not work with a cigarette stub -->"stub out" is pretty much a bull's eye, it's perfect.  The thesaurus that supplied the other verb phrases, did you wrong

@Mari-LouA You are right. The correct word from the thesaurus was snuff out. It was a typo.. I corrected it.
